# Run web browser from any server

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to start a web browser on the client from the node server? (without going through the website)

Not
"Visit website on node server-> redirect to another site"
I mean
"For example, send as post to node server with curl command (or something)-> start browser and go to any web site"

```
curl "http://sample/func" \
    -d "{\n  \"data\":\"1\"}" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are bound to the HTTP protocol, this is based on messages, no code execution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Response_message)

So, you cannot control on the server what happens on the client here.

In your example: curl does only print the servers response on stdout, no execution whatsoever.